# Zend Pdo_Mysql LOAD DATA forbidden

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdo, zend-db

I have been looking for a solution that allows load data queries with zend framework like:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '$dbFile' INTO TABLE mytable ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<object>';
```

When I try to execute this query, i get the following error:

```
Warning: PDO::exec() [pdo.exec]: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE forbidden
```

However if I output the query and copy/paste it into an editor like HeidiSQL the query works.
I searched for an answer and found that I should set the driver option **PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE** but it does not seem to work.

I would like to use application.ini to set the driver option:

```
resources.multidb.mydb.adapter = "Pdo_Mysql"
resources.multidb.mydb.dbname = "mydb"
resources.multidb.mydb.username = "myuser"
resources.multidb.mydb.password = "mypass"
resources.multidb.mydb.driver_options.PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE = true
resources.multidb.mydb.driver_options.1001 = true
```

I tried it the following way too but got the same error:

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini', 'testing');
$dbParams = $config->resources->multidb->mydb->toArray();
$dbParams['driver_options'] = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => '1');
$db = Zend_Db::factory($config->resources->multidb->mydb->adapter, $dbParams);
```

Am I overlooking something? Or maybe setting the options wrong? I also read that mysql must be compiled with --enable-load-data or something but the query works with an sql editor so it should work through php.

Comment: What are the permissions for the user you're connecting with? As well, the server and client can both be configured via .ini to disallow infile stuff, as it can be a security risk: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data-local.html

Comment: I am using a local wamp setup for development. I connect using the root user with no pass. All settings are default. I use the same root user when connecting with HeidiSQL (which executes load data). I found out that the keyword 'LOCAL' is the troublemaker and I didn't need it. Omitting this keyword no longer produces the error. It works for me now but I still would like to know how to enable 'LOCAL'. It must be something trivial like a setting, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I found an [interesting implementation](http://rend.googlecode.com/svn-history/r506/trunk/source/library/Rend/Factory/Database/Pdo/Mysql.php) of local infiles in the Rend (Rapid Zend) Framework.

Basically, the file has a class for the PDO object and has a method like this:

```
/**
 * Set the local infile flag
 *
 * @param boolean $allowLocalInfile
 * @return Rend_Factory_Database_Pdo_Mysql
 */
public function setAllowLocalInfile($allowLocalInfile)
{
    $this->_options["driver_options"][PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE] = $allowLocalInfile;
    return $this;
}
```

I'm sure some more browsing in that open source repository would reveal some tricks to solve your problem.